# Need caching system that's both fast and big

Tags: php, caching

Is there  a caching system in PhP that's both fast and big?

If I cache in disk the IO goes up.

If I cache in memory, the memory is small.

I need a comprehensive caching system that cache in memory, but when the memory goes big automatically dump large data sequentially to disk.

Any such thing in PhP?

The site store huge number of small items (30k) millions of them. Each data is stored in a file now

Comment: What are you trying to cache? Huge number of small items/small number of big items/...?

Comment: huge number of small items (30k) millions of them. Each data is stored in a file now.

Comment: Did you try [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)?

Comment: [Redis](http://redis.io) is a good software for caching, except if you approach the memory limit, but then again, you might want to have a look at [Distributed caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_cache)

Answer (score 1):

You should try one of these:

APC

XCACHE

EACCELERATOR

MEMCACHE

ZEND OPTIMIZER

These are the best PHP cache solutions available.

Comment: The question is not how to build a generic cache, but what solutions can allow a (tunable) trade-off between disk I/O and memory usage.

Comment: Apart from memcache, the solutions you list are mostly opcode caches. The way the question is phrased, it sounds like a generic data cache is needed instead.

Comment: Removed my -1 because the answer was edited into something completely different (might have made more sense to delete and add a new one).

Comment: @JimThio "opcode" refers to the compiled machine-ready form of PHP, which normally exists only briefly when a PHP file is loaded into memory and executed; an "opcode cache" keeps the compiled form of each file around, saving time next time that file is needed (e.g. for a different page load on the site).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want Redis. It's sort of like memcache but with disk based persistance/overflow.

Comment: Redis has persistence but not overflow, you cannot have a dataset that is bigger than memory. See the FAQ at http://redis.io/topics/faq